# PHP str_replace and or number_format failing

Tags: php, str-replace, number-formatting

```
      $BRL_PRICE = currency("USD", "BRL", $allmoney);
      echo "BRL1 = " . $BRL_PRICE."<br />";
      $BRL_PRICE = str_replace(" ", "", $BRL_PRICE);
      echo "BRL2 = " . $BRL_PRICE."<br />";  
      $BRL_PRICE = number_format($BRL_PRICE, 2);
      echo "BRL3 = " . $BRL_PRICE."<br />";
```

outputs are..

```
BRL1 = 1 531.70922
BRL2 = 1 531.70922
BRL3 = 1.00
```

All I really want is to round up the value to the nearest cents.. 10s place. I know number_format failures because currency() google money converter adds a space instead of a comra or blank.

I want

```
BRL3 = 1531.71
```

.

```
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = explode('"', $rawdata);
    $data = explode(' ', $data['3']);
    $var = $data['0'];
    return $var;
}
```

Comment: There is no function named `currency()` in PHP. Please explain.

Comment: I know it is more resource intensive but did you try `preg_replace`?   `$BRL_PRICE = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $BRL_PRICE);`  Your `str_replace` should work but it looks like maybe it is a tab?  Not sure..

Comment: @hakre, assume currency returns the first value which is `1 531.70922`

Comment: Good to see the code, but what is `$allmoney`?

Comment: zerkms's regular expression fixed it all `preg_replace('~[^\d.]~', '', $BRL);`  try the currency function yourself.. put in value of 810 convert from USD to BRL  `$BRL_PRICE = currency("USD", "BRL", 810);`

Comment: @hakre       `$allmoney = $_REQUEST['money'];` some isset / is_numeric if conditionals      `$allmoney = $allmoney > 0 ? $allmoney : 1;`  pretty much `810`

Comment: You're replacing the wrong space, this works: `str_replace("\xc2\xa0", "", $BRL_PRICE);`, no need for a regex ([answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681322/php-str-replace-and-or-number-format-failing/7681513#7681513))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't blame software in cases when you was just too lazy to read documentation:

```
$BRL_PRICE = number_format($BRL_PRICE, 2, '.', '');

echo number_format(1531.70922, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: `$BRL_PRICE = "1 531.71";` `echo "BRL = " . number_format($BRL_PRICE, 2, '.', '') ."<br />";`  outputs `BRL = 1.00` you what i think there could be some encoded character not space

Comment: This one also works for me after removing the space... it's weird that in your question BRL2 doesn't have the space removed after doing `str_replace`, try doing a `var_dump` of the first result to see if there's something besides a space

Comment: @SSpoke: if you understand it is your fail that you pass something-that-looks-like-a-space-but-is-not - why do you blame functions. Just write the code that will make your number a number. Like `preg_replace('~[^\d.]~', '', $BRL);`

Comment: works, after using the regular expression before it.. Thanks zermkms and everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `sprintf('%.2f',$var)`

Comment: `$BRL_PRICE = "1 531.71";` `echo "TEST = " . sprintf('%.2f',$BRL_PRICE) . "<br />";` `TEST = 1.00`

Comment: I believe he means after you do the `str_replace`, it works for me at least.

Comment: str_replace doesn't work i believe too, it's probably not a space

Comment: It's a space, but not the one you used in your `str_replace` call, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681322/php-str-replace-and-or-number-format-failing/7681513#7681513).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a simple space in your number.  Try `preg_replace` and see what happens:

```
$BRL_PRICE = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $BRL_PRICE);
```

Comment: This does not work unless you set the `u` modifier for `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

The response you get from google is invalid json. You don't even `json_decode` it, but just for the log.

`str_replace` works pretty well (as always), you just need to replace the right string:

```
$BRL_PRICE = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", "", $BRL_PRICE);
```

That is the Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0).